# NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.time.LocalDateTime$1

Tags: java

I'm using jdk 1.8_102.

Here's the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.time.LocalDateTime$1
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.plus(LocalDateTime.java:1185)
    at java.time.OffsetDateTime.plus(OffsetDateTime.java:1190)
    at java.time.OffsetDateTime.plus(OffsetDateTime.java:128)
    at java.time.Duration.addTo(Duration.java:1070)
    at java.time.OffsetDateTime.plus(OffsetDateTime.java:1159)
    at com.windlogics.commons.pi.operators.DstCompensatingSupport.getNextTimeStamp(DstCompensatingSupport.java:37)
```

I get this when I run from Eclipse or through maven install.

Here's the code at the bottom of the stack trace:

```
private Duration interval;

public OffsetDateTime getNextTimeStamp(OffsetDateTime current) {
    return current.plus(interval);
}
```

The Duration is initialized with Duration.ofMinutes(20).

The argument is initialized to OffsetDateTime.parse("2014-11-02T04:00:00Z") and then updated by calls to the getNextTimeStamp method.

Comment: wondering how do you intialize interval?

Comment: What are the values of the variables?

Comment: works fine for me. Also, I don't see any inner classes in the LocalDateTime src, but I'm running jdk 1.8.101. Maybe you have a classpath problem? Do you add any special jars for localdatetime? Can you show us all your dependencies/jar-files?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this stack trace is what appeared but I found out I had recently introduce some unintentional recursion (that's strangely not showing up in the stack trace).  Once I got rid of the recursion, this problem went away.  My suspicion is that the recursion may have pushed my timestamp values to the limit of what java.time likes to handle?

I'll leave this open for a bit in case someone knows how or why this happened.